# Why is the post increment operation executed if the line throws an exception?

Tags: c#

I came across a language behavior today that I wasn't expecting. Now I'm eager to learn why. Consider the following example:

```
try
{
    worksheet.AddCell(row, cell++, image.DisplayCaption());
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
    cell++;
    throw;
}
```

In my example, `image` was null causing this line to throw a `NullReferenceException`; however, `cell` was still incremented and, of course, it was incremented again in the catch block. Why was the first post increment operation executed? In addition, would it have been executed if `worksheet` was null?

Thanks, Pete

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arguments of method call are evaluated from left to right.

Instead of catching `NullRefereneException` use `if(image != null)`. Exceptions are slow.

Order of things happening:

1. `cell` is copied for the value parameter
2. `cell` is incremented as the last operation of the second parameter's expression: `cell++`
3. `image.DisplayCaption()`
4. `worksheet.AddCell(row, <non-incremented value>, <result of DisplayCaption()>);`

Since step 3. results in `NullReferenceException` step 4. doesn't happen.

Comment: Don't do it for reasons of speed - do it for reasons of clarity. You shouldn't use exceptions to handle situations you can very easily test for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just using this example to illustrate the behavior. You're saying if the NullReferenceException occurs to the left of the post increment, it won't be executed?

Comment: @slypete - yes, you're right (correct, not opposite of left ;-)

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. How is it possible for AddCell not to get called but cell still gets incremented? Typically the increment wouldn't occur until after AddCell returns. Why is it premature in this example?

Comment: The increment occurs *before* method call because the incremented values will be passed to the method. The same way `DisplayCaption` is called before `AddCell` call.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the order when using the pre-increment operator? The non-incremented value should be passed to the method when using the post-increment operator, no?

Comment: @JakubKonecki `cell` is incremented twice in this example.

Comment: I have and am trying to understand why the first post-increment operation is being executed. You and I are on the same page thinking that it should have been skipped. With the help of the community, I'm looking forward to learning why it wasn't.

Comment: @JakubKonecki hey, my friend showed me section 7.5.1.2 of the C# specification, and now I think your original answer was headed in the right direction. Each expression of the argument list is evaluated from left to right. Since it's a pass-by-value parameter, a copy of the non-incremented value is taken for the method parameter and immediately incremented as the last step of the expression in that argument. If you agree, will you revert and expand on your original answer, so I can mark it as best?